"Abstract" presentation of $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$
I understand that $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$ is finitely generated, and one can exhibit matrices $S$ and $T$ that generate it. It is often stated that there is also an "abstract" presentation
$$
\langle S,T | S^4 = 1, (ST)^3 = 1 \rangle
$$
The $S$ and $T$ matrices clearly satisfy these relations. My question is: is this a complete set of relations (note I'm not interested in $PSL(2,\mathbb Z)$, which would have $S^2=1$)? How can one (dis)prove it?
If it is so, the entire information about the group structure should be deducible from that presentation. For example, at the level of matrices one sees that $S^2 = -\mathrm{Id}$ and this element is thus central. I am however unable to reproduce the same result using the relations above only, that is without adding the relation $S^2 T = T S^2$. This seems to suggest that the relations above are not a complete set.

This is not a complete set of relations; I think it's complete after adding the relation $S^2 T = T S^2$ asserting that $S^2$ is central. I have more commonly seen the presentation given in terms of an amalgamated free product $C_4 \ast_{C_2} C_6$, which means explicitly two generators $a, b$ satisfying $a^4 = b^6 = e, a^2 = b^3$; see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2569489/sl-2-mathbbz-is-an-amalgamated-product.

The group $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$ does not have a presentation of the form that you wrote. If you substitute $U=ST$ into that presentation, then you can eliminate $T$ and rewrite your presentation in the form
$$\langle S,U \mid S^4=1, U^3=1 \rangle
$$
This is a presentation of the free product $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z * \mathbb Z / 3 \mathbb Z$. But that group has trivial center --- indeed, any free product of nontrivial groups has trivial center --- whereas the center of $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$ contains $-\text{Id}$.
So no, despite what you may have have seen often stated, that is not a presentation of $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$.
In fact, I believe that $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$ cannot even be obtained from that presentation by adding more relators. In other words, there is no surjective homomrophism from $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z * \mathbb Z / 3 \mathbb Z$ onto $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$. For if there were, I believe one could work with the quotient homomorphism
$$SL(2,\mathbb Z) \mapsto SL(2,\mathbb Z) / \underbrace{\text{(center)}}_{=\{\pm \text{Id}\}} \to PSL(2,\mathbb Z)
$$
to prove that $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$ has no element of order $6$, contradicting that $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ has order $6$.
Regarding that presentation you wrote, your post does not say what matrices $S$ and $T$ you actually had in mind. But as indicated in the comment of @QiaochuYuan, if one takes $S = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $U = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ then one obtains the presentation
$$SL(2,\mathbb Z) \approx \langle S,U \mid S^4=U^6=1, S^2=U^3\rangle
$$
